# Using the index of an item in a repeater view in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a repeater view which's item source is an observable collection of view models and which has a data template. Now I want to use the index of the specific item to be used inside the data template. Is there any way to achieve this? 
NOTE: The repeater view is part of UXDivers.Artina Library, but it should expose the same API as a listview and thus a solution that would work for a listview, would probably also work for the repeater.

Here is the code I have so far:

**Xaml:**

```
<ctlRep:Repeater
        ItemsSource="{ Binding ListItems }"
        Padding="10, 10"
        Spacing="10"
        Orientation="Vertical">
        <ctlRep:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <elements:StructuredVideoDescriptionItemTemplate />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ctlRep:Repeater.ItemTemplate>
</ctlRep:Repeater>
```

**Viewmodel:**

```
public class VideoDescriptionStructureListItem : ObservableObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsNumberic { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListItems { get; set; }
}
```

Inside the data template I would like to have access to the ListItems item (which is a string) and the index of the specific item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be the solution you are looking for, but I have solved the exact issue lately with the following strategy

- Introduce an intermediate object that contains a property for an index
- Build an `ObservableCollection` of those objects instead of `string` objects and assign the correct indices
- Bind to the string and the index instead of the direct object

The class may look like this:

```
class VideoDescriptionViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public int Index { get; private set; }

    public VideoDescriptionViewModel(string description, int index)
    {
        Description = description;
        Index = index;
    }
}
```

and you can build the instances like

```
var videoDescriptionViewModels = videoDescriptions.Select((description, index) => new VideoDescriptionViewModel(description, index));
```

and bind it from your XAML

```
<elements:StructuredVideoDescriptionItemTemplate Description="{Binding Description}" 
                                                 Id="{Binding Id}" />
```